# laravel old input function not working for radio button

Tags: laravel

Good day!

im migrating my application from php to php with laravel. im doing this online questionnaire which fetch the questions from the database. the answer should be YES or NO or NA only . so im using a radio button for this. im having a hard time displaying the old input of the user once they submit the form.

```
 @foreach($questions as $question)
                            <p><b>{{$question->sort_order}}. </b>  {{$question->questions}}</p>
                            <div class="radio" style="margin-left: 20px;">  


                                <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q{{$question->id}}" value="YES" {{old('q'.$question->id)=="YES" ? 'checked='.'"checked"' : ''}}>Yes</label>
                                <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q{{$question->id}}" value="NO" {{old('q'.$question->id)=="NO" ? 'checked='.'"checked"' : ''}}>No</label>      
                                <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q{{$question->id}}" value="NA" {{old('q'.$question->id)=="NA" ? 'checked='.'"checked"' : ''}}>N/A</label>   
                            </div>   

                                <div class="form-group">                     
                                    <label class="control-label" for="remark">Remarks:</label>
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control" name="r{{$question->id}}" placeholder="" value=""> 

                                    <hr>

                                </div>  
                    @endforeach
```

thank you in advance.

arnel

this is what happen when i post the page.. i answered all questionnaire except no. 23.. but all buttons have no old input.

[page once posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze5HA.png)

Comment: question id is string??

Comment: question id is an integer however i'm adding "q" for each id as the variable name for the each question and "r" for each remark.

Comment: show the html source code after returned old(), DON'T save as image, code only, you post image, we can't copy the code for test

Comment: oh im so.. sorry..

Comment: show the html source code of the 'page once posted', just copy and paste the line include `<input type="radio"`

Comment: <div class="radio" style="margin-left: 20px;">       
                                    <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q417" value="YES"  >Yes</label>
                                    <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q417" value="NO"  >No</label>      
                                    <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q417" value="NA"  >N/A</label>   
                                </div>

Comment: can you try replace with {{old('q'.$question->id)}} and show html source code after error

Comment: highlight your code and press ctrl+k here

Comment: i did that already.. i think i posted the old code. but its now {{old(q.$question->id}} and still same thing

Comment: @foreach($questions as $question)
    <p>{{old('q'.$question->id)}}</p> {{-- put this line under the @foreach, it display q417 or empty ? --}}

Comment: <p></p> 
<p><b>1. </b>  Was the manager-on-duty is &quot;Managing-by-Walking-Around&quot; using A.I.M. Scorecard?</p>
<div class="radio" style="margin-left: 20px;">       
                                    <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q417" value="YES"  >Yes</label>
                                    <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q417" value="NO"  >No</label>      
                                    <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q417" value="NA"  >N/A</label>  </div>

Comment: its empty.. <p></p>

Comment: read again the document https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: because your old() always is empty or null

Answer (score 0):

Change `old("q$question->id")` to `old('q' . $question->id)`. That will do the trick.

Comment: No there isn't. Because you already start using php with {{}} tags.
"q$question->id" is string. You must change like Thierry's said.

Comment: <label style="margin-right: 20px"><input type="radio" name="q{{$question->id}}" value="YES"  {{old('q'.$question->id)=="YES" ? 'checked='.'"checked"' : ''}}>Yes</label>